# dotnet build from CLI returns, "NuGet.targets(132,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!" How do I build my solution?

Tags: .net, build, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a solution file from dotnet CLI, and it says
`NuGet.targets(132,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!`
But then it prints the full path and name of the solution file, so it clearly *is* finding what I am trying to build.

I have web-searched the returned message and nothing similar to it comes up.

I tried:

```
dotnet build  
dotnet build -c Release  
dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -r win-x64 --self-contained true
```

They all return the same message. I was following a tutorial, and my expectation was that a `\bin \ (build type)` folder would be created with the built project files output to it. How do I get a solution to build from dotnet CLI?

Here is the dir output:

```
11/02/2022  12:11 AM    <DIR>          .  
11/02/2022  12:11 AM    <DIR>          ..  
10/31/2022  07:29 PM               122 .gitignore  
10/31/2022  07:29 PM    <DIR>          Assets  
10/31/2022  07:30 PM    <DIR>          CSharpBeginner.Game  
10/31/2022  07:29 PM               540 CSharpBeginner.sln  
10/31/2022  07:30 PM    <DIR>          CSharpBeginner.Windows  
10/31/2022  07:29 PM    <DIR>          Resources
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the output of `ls` or `dir` of that folder. Nobody can help if you provided not enough information.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I have updated the question to include the dir output.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the warning was caused by forgetting to add a project to the solutions file with

```
dotnet sln add <path_to_project_fsproj>
```

For a concrete example, omitting Step 3. below resulted in a warning when issuing `dotnet build`:

```
# Step 1.
dotnet new sln --output MyProject

# Step 2.
dotnet new classlib -lang "F#" -o src/Domains

# Step 3.
dotnet sln add src/Domains/Domains.fsproj
```

Docs used:

- [Get started with F# with command-line tools - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line)

  Apart from Step 1., the `dotnet` commands are language-agnostic.
- [What are Visual Studio solutions & projects? - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)
- [Project Solution (.sln) file - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022)
- [dotnet sln command - .NET CLI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln)
- [dotnet new  - .NET CLI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)